# Insurance — Intentional act by someone else

Tags: liability, insurance, car-insurance

Some young punk steals your car and goes on a rampage, *a la* the chase in the beginning of *Mad Max*. In the process, he cripples several people and causes severe property damage. Can the injured parties make a valid claim against your insurance?

From what I understand, if you were going on a rampage in your own car, your insurance company would be off the hook since it was an intentional act. However, while the rampage in this scenario is an intentional act, it isn't an intentional act by the policyholder.

Answer (score 3):

Your insurance policy is probably not liable, but not due to the intentional act exclusion.

Insurance only comes into play when the insured is legally liable for something.

Non-driver liability for harm caused by an automobile is a matter about which different countries and U.S. states differ. Liability on the basis of ownership of the car is a minority rule. Most jurisdictions do not follow that rule.

Generally speaking, however, no jurisdiction makes the owner of a car liable for a car thief's actions with the car, in the absence of negligence by the owner of the car.

For example, if the car was entrusted to a nine-year old, or left running with the keys in the ignition next to a bus letting off prisoners for a court appearance, the car owner might have negligence liability. But, generally speaking, the car owner will have no liability, and hence the car owner's insurance policy won't be implicated.

> From what I understand, if you were going on a rampage in your own
> car, your insurance company would be off the hook since it was an
> intentional act.

Correct.